# How can I construct this complex ActiveRecord query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, geocoding, arel

I have a bus model and an event model. Each bus is going to an event:

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :origin
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buses
end
```

As you can see, each bus also has an origin (the place it leaves from). An origin can have many buses leaving from it. Origins are geocoded (by the `[Geocoder gem][1]`) on creation so that they have a latitude and longitude associated with them.

```
class Origin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buses
  geocoded_by :full_address

  def full_address
    # returns the full address of the origin
  end
end
```

The geocoding also furnishes them with a `near` scope so that I can search for `Origin.near([lat, long])`.

So, what I'm trying to do is find the bus which is going to `@event` and which has it's origin closest to `[@lat, @long]`.

Something like this:

```
Bus.where(:event_id => @event.id)
   .joins(:origin)
   .near([@lat, @long])
   .first
```

But of course, that errors out because `Bus.where.joins` returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but the `near` scope is on the `Origin` class.

```
undefined method `near' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x000001053b36d8>
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
It just occurred to me that I can add `has_many :through` associations to `Event` and `Origin`. Not sure if that helps though?

Answer (score -1):

I think the join is sensless! Why dont you do it like this?

```
@event.buses.each do |bus|
      bus.origin.near([@lat, @long])
      _do sth,..._
end
```

Beacause origin is already associatied with bus and you already have @event.

Comment: I'm trying to keep everything working with ActiveRecord Relations and scopes. As I understand it, if an event had 6000 buses going to it (bear with me for a second), rails would load them all into memory and iterate over each one of them. Afaik there it a better way.